# Report Builder 3.0 Creating a expressions with different data types

Tags: expression, reportbuilder3.0

I've added 4 fields to the SQL for my report in Report Builder 3.0.  the first 3 fields are Decimal (5) and the last one is Varchar (81).  The report runs fine but I want to combine the 4 fields in an expression in the layout.  This is what I have:

```
=Fields!TEAM_ID.Value & '  ' & Fields!GRP_ID.Value & '  ' & Fields!TERR_ID.Value & '  ' & Fields!LNAM.Value
```

When I try to run the report, I get an error message that says "The value expression....contains an error.  Express expected.

I have 2 questions:

(1)  What is wrong with this expression?
(2)  How can I paid the first 3 fields with 0 (zeros).  Each of the firstr 3 fields should be 3 characters long, e.g., 76 should be 076, 1 should be 001, etc.

Thanks for the help........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should use double quotes instead of single quotes

2) Use Format() function

```
=Format(Fields!TEAM_ID.Value,"000") & "  " & Format(Fields!GRP_ID.Value,"000") & "  " & Format(Fields!TERR_ID.Value,"000") & "  " & Fields!LNAM.Value
```